# Using MySql SELECT FROM JOIN with PDO connection with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am new to programming and PHP. I have 3 tables:

**Products**

- product_id
- name
- quantity

**Users**

- customerID
- username
- password

**Cart**

- product_id
- customerID
- quantity

I would like to join all this tables in order to visualize on my cart page the product name and quantity selected by the specific customer(that's why customerID in cart table) that is logged in. This is the code I have:

```
$customer_id = $_SESSION['customerID'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare(
"SELECT * FROM products
JOIN cart ON products.product_id = cart.product_id
JOIN users ON cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = :customerID"
);

$statement->bindParam(':customerID', $customer_id);

$statement->execute();
$cart = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And then I loop through $cart to display its content.

The problem is that righ now I get to see the list of products selected by all the different customers have been logged in previously. Not only the user which is logged at the moment.
Basically every customer can see each other selection of products in the cart.

Inside the login.php file I have created, I store the customerID in a Session like this:

```
$_SESSION['customerID'] = $fetched_user["customerID"];
```

But I am not sure how to recall the session into the pdo connection.

Comment: Use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php for some instructions. or: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @xQbert will I still need to use JOIN or only SELECT * FROM products and than bindParam(':name', $name);?

Comment: Generally speaking it's always best to execute 1 query getting precisely all the data you will need at that moment.  Since you're after the products and quantities in a specific customers cart, continuing to use the join makes sense.  You'll just be adding a `WHERE Users.CustomerID = :CustomerID` Normally it is also recommended to select just the needed fields not `Select *`  this aids in performance as well and prevents unforeseen events should the tables structures change  and should you have dynamic code showing all columns from the resultset.

Comment: @xQbert You mean like this: JOIN users ON cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = :customerID and then I execute the :customerID with variable that contains the session of customerID?

Comment: Yes you would bind the variable for $customerID to the parameter :CustomerID and then execute the statement.  the result set would then only contain the dataset for that specific customer all fields unless you change the `Select *`. See example 1: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php  Fetching rows from a prepared query would be identical to that from a query without parameters

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on the surface...   can you echo out the $customer_ID and ensure it's value is properly getting set from the session? and the statement: [debugDumpParams();](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

Comment: So, $customer_id is right, I double checked on the database. While on echo $statement I get this error: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string. But I want to clarify that I have eco the $customer_id before the prepare. Tell me if that is wrong, 'cause I am new to this

Comment: Yeah you ened to use debugDumpParams to echo out the prepared statement. edited comment above to show a link on how to use it.  This looks right;   I'm just missing something. Right value is assigned the desired CustomerID is listed in the echo... ; prepared statement looks right; it just seems that it's ignoring the where clause.  Maybe someone else will see something I'm not.

Comment: This is what I get whit debugDumpParams. 21SQL: [148] SELECT * FROM products JOIN cart ON products.product_id = cart.product_id JOIN users ON cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = :customerID Sent SQL: [141] SELECT * FROM products JOIN cart ON products.product_id = cart.product_id JOIN users ON cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = '21' Params: 1 Key: Name: [11] :customerID paramno=-1 name=[11] ":customerID" is_param=1 param_type=2

Comment: I think `JOIN users ON cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = :customerID` should be `JOIN users ON users.customerID = cart.customerID WHERE users.customerID = :customerID"`. You only got half an `ON` clause, which goes unnoticed because of the `WHERE` clause, which you may want to put on the next line.

Comment: YES! It's working perfectly now! Many thanks for your patience and time!!!

Comment: @GolezTrol nice.  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Took me a couple of ticks too. After all, the userid was in there, so why didn't it work? It had to be in the joins somewhere. I was looking for an inner join on itself, which is also a common mistake, writing `a.id=a.id` instead of `a.id=b.id`, effectively turning it into a cross join. But then I saw this condition basically saying 'join every user, if `cart.customerID` has *any* value', also behaving almost as a cross join. Many other databases, like Oracle, won't even accept this query, but in MySQL it's valid, though in this case definitely unwanted.